# Error while building code for SQLCipher

Tags: iphone, ios, sql, cocoa, sqlcipher

I followed all the steps which are listed [here](http://sqlcipher.net/ios-tutorial/) , but I don't know why I am not able to build the project. I got some compiler errors as

```
/Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Intermediates/sqlcipher.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/amalgamation.build/Script-9069D08A0FCE185A0042E34C.sh: ./configure: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

According to this compiler is not able to find a file named "Script-9069D08A0FCE185A0042E34C.sh" which results in error

```
Command /bin/sh emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure
```

and finally failing compiling with exit code 1

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

output of compiler is as

```
PhaseScriptExecution "Run Script" /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Intermediates/sqlcipher.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/amalgamation.build/Script-9069D08A0FCE185A0042E34C.sh
cd /Users/macbook2/SQLCipher2
setenv ACTION build
setenv ALTERNATE_GROUP staff
setenv ALTERNATE_MODE u+w,go-w,a+rX
setenv ALTERNATE_OWNER macbook2
setenv ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS YES
setenv APPLE_INTERNAL_DEVELOPER_DIR /AppleInternal/Developer
setenv APPLE_INTERNAL_DIR /AppleInternal
setenv APPLE_INTERNAL_DOCUMENTATION_DIR /AppleInternal/Documentation
setenv APPLE_INTERNAL_LIBRARY_DIR /AppleInternal/Library
setenv APPLE_INTERNAL_TOOLS /AppleInternal/Developer/Tools
setenv APPLY_RULES_IN_COPY_FILES NO
setenv ARCHS i386
setenv ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT i386
setenv ARCHS_UNIVERSAL_IPHONE_OS i386
setenv AVAILABLE_PLATFORMS "iphonesimulator macosx iphoneos"
setenv BUILD_COMPONENTS "headers build"
setenv BUILD_DIR /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Products
setenv BUILD_ROOT /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Products
setenv BUILD_STYLE 
setenv BUILD_VARIANTS normal
setenv BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
setenv CACHE_ROOT /var/folders/lq/qxx4dw1s2_957n31bhdw38400000gn/C/com.apple.Xcode.501
setenv CCHROOT /var/folders/lq/qxx4dw1s2_957n31bhdw38400000gn/C/com.apple.Xcode.501
setenv CHMOD /bin/chmod
setenv CHOWN /usr/sbin/chown
setenv CLASS_FILE_DIR /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Intermediates/sqlcipher.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/amalgamation.build/JavaClasses
setenv CLEAN_PRECOMPS YES
setenv CLONE_HEADERS NO
setenv CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/
setenv COMBINE_HIDPI_IMAGES YES
setenv COMMAND_MODE legacy
setenv COMPOSITE_SDK_DIRS /var/folders/lq/qxx4dw1s2_957n31bhdw38400000gn/C/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs
setenv COMPRESS_PNG_FILES YES
setenv CONFIGURATION Debug
setenv CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
setenv CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Intermediates/sqlcipher.build/Debug-iphonesimulator
setenv COPYING_PRESERVES_HFS_DATA NO
setenv COPY_PHASE_STRIP NO
setenv COPY_RESOURCES_FROM_STATIC_FRAMEWORKS YES
setenv CP /bin/cp
setenv CURRENT_ARCH i386
setenv CURRENT_VARIANT normal
setenv DEAD_CODE_STRIPPING NO
setenv DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS YES
setenv DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT dwarf-with-dsym
setenv DEFAULT_COMPILER com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0
setenv DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION NO
setenv DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING NO
setenv DERIVED_FILES_DIR /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Intermediates/sqlcipher.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/amalgamation.build/DerivedSources
setenv DERIVED_FILE_DIR /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Intermediates/sqlcipher.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/amalgamation.build/DerivedSources
setenv DERIVED_SOURCES_DIR /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Intermediates/sqlcipher.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/amalgamation.build/DerivedSources
setenv DEVELOPER_APPLICATIONS_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications
setenv DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
setenv DEVELOPER_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
setenv DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks
setenv DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR_QUOTED "\"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks\""
setenv DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library
setenv DEVELOPER_SDK_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs
setenv DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools
setenv DEVELOPER_USR_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr
setenv DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE English
setenv DO_HEADER_SCANNING_IN_JAM NO
setenv DSTROOT /tmp/sqlcipher.dst
setenv DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
setenv DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME .dSYM
setenv DWARF_DSYM_FILE_SHOULD_ACCOMPANY_PRODUCT NO
setenv DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
setenv EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME -iphonesimulator
setenv ENABLE_HEADER_DEPENDENCIES YES
setenv EXCLUDED_INSTALLSRC_SUBDIRECTORY_PATTERNS ".DS_Store .svn .git .hg CVS"
setenv EXCLUDED_RECURSIVE_SEARCH_PATH_SUBDIRECTORIES "*.nib *.lproj *.framework *.gch (*) .DS_Store CVS .svn .git .hg *.xcodeproj *.xcode *.pbproj *.pbxproj"
setenv FILE_LIST /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Intermediates/sqlcipher.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/amalgamation.build/Objects/LinkFileList
setenv FIXED_FILES_DIR /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Intermediates/sqlcipher.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/amalgamation.build/FixedFiles
setenv FRAMEWORK_VERSION A
setenv GCC3_VERSION 3.3
setenv GCC_C_LANGUAGE_STANDARD c99
setenv GCC_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC NO
setenv GCC_OBJC_LEGACY_DISPATCH YES
setenv GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL 0
setenv GCC_PFE_FILE_C_DIALECTS "c objective-c c++ objective-c++"
setenv GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS NO
setenv GCC_VERSION com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0
setenv GCC_WARN_ABOUT_RETURN_TYPE YES
setenv GCC_WARN_UNUSED_VARIABLE YES
setenv GENERATE_MASTER_OBJECT_FILE NO
setenv GENERATE_PKGINFO_FILE NO
setenv GENERATE_PROFILING_CODE NO
setenv GID 20
setenv GROUP staff
setenv HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_FLAT_ENTRIES_FOR_TARGET_BEING_BUILT YES
setenv HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_FRAMEWORK_ENTRIES_FOR_ALL_PRODUCT_TYPES YES
setenv HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_NONPUBLIC_NONPRIVATE_HEADERS YES
setenv HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_PROJECT_HEADERS YES
setenv HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS " /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include"
setenv ICONV /usr/bin/iconv
setenv INFOPLIST_EXPAND_BUILD_SETTINGS YES
setenv INFOPLIST_OUTPUT_FORMAT binary
setenv INFOPLIST_PREPROCESS NO
setenv INSTALL_DIR /tmp/sqlcipher.dst
setenv INSTALL_GROUP staff
setenv INSTALL_MODE_FLAG u+w,go-w,a+rX
setenv INSTALL_OWNER macbook2
setenv INSTALL_ROOT /tmp/sqlcipher.dst
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.1
setenv JAVAC_DEFAULT_FLAGS "-J-Xms64m -J-XX:NewSize=4M -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF8"
setenv JAVA_APP_STUB /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Resources/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
setenv JAVA_ARCHIVE_CLASSES YES
setenv JAVA_ARCHIVE_TYPE JAR
setenv JAVA_COMPILER /usr/bin/javac
setenv JAVA_FRAMEWORK_RESOURCES_DIRS Resources
setenv JAVA_JAR_FLAGS cv
setenv JAVA_SOURCE_SUBDIR .
setenv JAVA_USE_DEPENDENCIES YES
setenv JAVA_ZIP_FLAGS -urg
setenv JIKES_DEFAULT_FLAGS "+E +OLDCSO"
setenv KEEP_PRIVATE_EXTERNS NO
setenv LD_GENERATE_MAP_FILE NO
setenv LD_MAP_FILE_PATH /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Intermediates/sqlcipher.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/amalgamation.build/amalgamation-LinkMap-normal-i386.txt
setenv LD_NO_PIE NO
setenv LEGACY_DEVELOPER_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer
setenv LEX lex
setenv LINKER_DISPLAYS_MANGLED_NAMES NO
setenv LINK_FILE_LIST_normal_i386 
setenv LINK_WITH_STANDARD_LIBRARIES YES
setenv LOCAL_ADMIN_APPS_DIR /Applications/Utilities
setenv LOCAL_APPS_DIR /Applications
setenv LOCAL_DEVELOPER_DIR /Library/Developer
setenv LOCAL_LIBRARY_DIR /Library
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv MAC_OS_X_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION 11G63
setenv MAC_OS_X_VERSION_ACTUAL 1075
setenv MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAJOR 1070
setenv MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MINOR 0705
setenv NATIVE_ARCH i386
setenv NATIVE_ARCH_32_BIT i386
setenv NATIVE_ARCH_64_BIT x86_64
setenv NATIVE_ARCH_ACTUAL x86_64
setenv NO_COMMON YES
setenv OBJC_ABI_VERSION 2
setenv OBJECT_FILE_DIR /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Intermediates/sqlcipher.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/amalgamation.build/Objects
setenv OBJECT_FILE_DIR_normal /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Intermediates/sqlcipher.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/amalgamation.build/Objects-normal
setenv OBJROOT /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Intermediates
setenv ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH YES
setenv OPENSSL_SRC /Users/macbook2/MyApp/openssl-1.0.0e
setenv OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL 0
setenv OS MACOS
setenv OSAC /usr/bin/osacompile
setenv PASCAL_STRINGS YES
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/libexec:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
setenv PATH_PREFIXES_EXCLUDED_FROM_HEADER_DEPENDENCIES "/usr/include /usr/local/include /System/Library/Frameworks /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Headers /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/SDKs /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms"
setenv PKGINFO_FILE_PATH /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Intermediates/sqlcipher.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/amalgamation.build/PkgInfo
setenv PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_APPLICATIONS_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications
setenv PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin
setenv PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer/Library
setenv PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_SDK_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs
setenv PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Tools
setenv PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_USR_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr
setenv PLATFORM_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform
setenv PLATFORM_NAME iphonesimulator
setenv PLATFORM_PREFERRED_ARCH i386
setenv PLATFORM_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION 10B141
setenv PLATFORM_VERSION_AVAILABILITY_H_FORMAT 60100
setenv PLIST_FILE_OUTPUT_FORMAT binary
setenv PRECOMPS_INCLUDE_HEADERS_FROM_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR YES
setenv PRECOMP_DESTINATION_DIR /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Intermediates/sqlcipher.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/amalgamation.build/PrefixHeaders
setenv PRESERVE_DEAD_CODE_INITS_AND_TERMS NO
setenv PRODUCT_NAME amalgamation
setenv PRODUCT_SETTINGS_PATH 
setenv PROFILING_CODE NO
setenv PROJECT sqlcipher
setenv PROJECT_DERIVED_FILE_DIR /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Intermediates/sqlcipher.build/DerivedSources
setenv PROJECT_DIR /Users/macbook2/SQLCipher2
setenv PROJECT_FILE_PATH /Users/macbook2/SQLCipher2/sqlcipher.xcodeproj
setenv PROJECT_NAME sqlcipher
setenv PROJECT_TEMP_DIR /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Intermediates/sqlcipher.build
setenv PROJECT_TEMP_ROOT /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Intermediates
setenv RECURSIVE_SEARCH_PATHS_FOLLOW_SYMLINKS YES
setenv REMOVE_CVS_FROM_RESOURCES YES
setenv REMOVE_GIT_FROM_RESOURCES YES
setenv REMOVE_HG_FROM_RESOURCES YES
setenv REMOVE_SVN_FROM_RESOURCES YES
setenv REZ_COLLECTOR_DIR /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Intermediates/sqlcipher.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/amalgamation.build/ResourceManagerResources
setenv REZ_OBJECTS_DIR /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Intermediates/sqlcipher.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/amalgamation.build/ResourceManagerResources/Objects
setenv RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER NO
setenv SCAN_ALL_SOURCE_FILES_FOR_INCLUDES NO
setenv SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_0 /Users/macbook2/SQLCipher2/sqlite3.c
setenv SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_COUNT 1
setenv SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0 /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libsqlcipher.a
setenv SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_COUNT 1
setenv SDKROOT /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk
setenv SDK_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk
setenv SDK_NAME iphonesimulator6.1
setenv SDK_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION 10B141
setenv SED /usr/bin/sed
setenv SEPARATE_STRIP NO
setenv SEPARATE_SYMBOL_EDIT NO
setenv SET_DIR_MODE_OWNER_GROUP YES
setenv SET_FILE_MODE_OWNER_GROUP NO
setenv SHARED_DERIVED_FILE_DIR /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DerivedSources
setenv SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders
setenv SKIP_INSTALL YES
setenv SOURCE_ROOT /Users/macbook2/SQLCipher2
setenv SRCROOT /Users/macbook2/SQLCipher2
setenv STRINGS_FILE_OUTPUT_ENCODING binary
setenv STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT YES
setenv STRIP_STYLE all
setenv SUPPORTED_DEVICE_FAMILIES "1 2"
setenv SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS "iphonesimulator macosx iphoneos"
setenv SYMROOT /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Products
setenv SYSTEM_ADMIN_APPS_DIR /Applications/Utilities
setenv SYSTEM_APPS_DIR /Applications
setenv SYSTEM_CORE_SERVICES_DIR /System/Library/CoreServices
setenv SYSTEM_DEMOS_DIR /Applications/Extras
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_APPS_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DEMOS_DIR "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Built Examples"
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DOC_DIR "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC Reference Library"
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_GRAPHICS_TOOLS_DIR "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Graphics Tools"
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_JAVA_TOOLS_DIR "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Java Tools"
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_PERFORMANCE_TOOLS_DIR "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Performance Tools"
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_RELEASENOTES_DIR "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC Reference Library/releasenotes"
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DOC_DIR "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC Reference Library/documentation/DeveloperTools"
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_RELEASENOTES_DIR "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC Reference Library/releasenotes/DeveloperTools"
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_USR_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_UTILITIES_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Utilities
setenv SYSTEM_DOCUMENTATION_DIR /Library/Documentation
setenv SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DIR /System/Library
setenv TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY 1
setenv TARGETNAME amalgamation
setenv TARGET_BUILD_DIR /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
setenv TARGET_NAME amalgamation
setenv TARGET_TEMP_DIR /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Intermediates/sqlcipher.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/amalgamation.build
setenv TEMP_DIR /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Intermediates/sqlcipher.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/amalgamation.build
setenv TEMP_FILES_DIR /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Intermediates/sqlcipher.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/amalgamation.build
setenv TEMP_FILE_DIR /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Intermediates/sqlcipher.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/amalgamation.build
setenv TEMP_ROOT /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Intermediates
setenv TEST_AFTER_BUILD NO
setenv TOOLCHAINS com.apple.dt.toolchain.XcodeDefault
setenv UID 501
setenv UNSTRIPPED_PRODUCT NO
setenv USER macbook2
setenv USER_APPS_DIR /Users/macbook2/Applications
setenv USER_LIBRARY_DIR /Users/macbook2/Library
setenv USE_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC YES
setenv USE_HEADERMAP YES
setenv USE_HEADER_SYMLINKS NO
setenv VALIDATE_PRODUCT NO
setenv VALID_ARCHS i386
setenv VERBOSE_PBXCP NO
setenv VERSION_INFO_BUILDER macbook2
setenv VERSION_INFO_FILE amalgamation_vers.c
setenv VERSION_INFO_STRING "\"@(#)PROGRAM:amalgamation  PROJECT:sqlcipher-\""
setenv XCODE_APP_SUPPORT_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode
setenv XCODE_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION 4H1503
setenv XCODE_VERSION_ACTUAL 0463
setenv XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR 0400
setenv XCODE_VERSION_MINOR 0460
setenv YACC yacc
/bin/sh -c /Users/macbook2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acboozafiejdawbpwucjmgcisgvy/Build/Intermediates/sqlcipher.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/amalgamation.build/Script-9069D08A0FCE185A0042E34C.sh
```

could you please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: I drilled the problem down, and found that the line which is creating problem for me is './configure: /bin/sh^M'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because i was using xcode 4.6 instead of xcode 4.2 which was assumed by the tutorial. Now I am using the paid version of SQLCipher.